# Arabic text in a testefield In Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, amfphp

i am developing an application that gets comment data from database (i use amfphp to communicate with database).I've set caracter encoding in both gateway.php and my data base and everything is ok .

i traced the return value and it display correctlly in the outpout pane but when i set the .text property of the text field to the value it displays weird caracters. I tried to set a hard coded string in arabic and it works.I don't know where is the problem exactelly

(update)

```
textFeild.text = "امين"// text display fine
textFeild.text = textDataFromAMFPHP // weird caracters
trace( textDataFromAMFPHP ) // display fine  "امين"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your required characters are embedded in the font you're using for the text box you're targeting. This is needed for adding text dynamically. Embedding is only automatic for static text boxes with the text already placed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've embedded all the arabic characters with the font that you might need to use. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSB2C1B8DA-8C49-484c-A6B3-607E547BAB56.html (start reading where it says select and embed a range of fonts).

Comment: i've already done this that's why i said that this a weird thing